# How do I save my edit to my rc.local file?

Tags: gpio

I am totally new to Raspberry Pi and I am not a programmer so be gentle. I am adding some power button hardware to my Raspberry Pi, but before I can add the hardware I am taking the preliminary steps required to get it running. I am at the last step which is to enter three lines of code in my rc.local file. Neither the instructions found here:
http://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/Power_Button_For_RPi_SKU:_EP-0077#How_to_wire_it_up
or the video tutorial found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhEoGZshiPM&feature=youtu.be care to explain how I go about actually saving the rc.local file once I have edited it. I am accessing my RPi remotely using Putty and entering the lines of code but I don't know how to save it. Can someone help me?

Comment: What editor are you using to make the edits? What is the exact command you are using to make the changes?

Comment: The editor you use will have a command to save the file.  Look at the documentation for the editor you plan to use.  This is only tangentially related to the Pi.

Comment: I am remoting in to the Raspberry Pi using Putty. I am typing "sudo vim.tiny /etc/rc.local" without quotes and then I am entering the 3 requisite lines of code. This is where I am stuck. I tried removing the card and looking for an rc.local file to edit with Notepad ++ but I cannot find such a file but I can edit it with Putty. I just don't know how to save the changes.

Comment: Windows only accepts a single partition on removable media. If you want to edit it from your desktop, it'll require a Linux install, or Virtual Machine.

Comment: Do you not know how to use vim? What happens when you try and write a random hello world file in your home directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is, when finished with my edits to press ESC and then type ":wq" without quotes and press Enter.

Comment: That is not putty that is the vi or vim command to save and exit. You should look for a vi(m) tutorial and cheat sheet. Putty has no impact here you would still use esc :wq if you were using a keyboard and monitor directly connected to your Pi.

Comment: Your comment has me really confused now. What I did worked, the rc.local file saved and the hardware power button is working, so now I am not sure why it saved if you say that Putty has nothing to do with the rc.local file saving.

Comment: the esc :wc command is not a putty command it is a VIM command. In your answer, you say "I now realize this question is specifically related to how to use Putty to save files." It is not a putty command. Putty is the tool used to connect to your Pi and get a terminal, but editing files is done with an editor (VIM in your case). Editors save files not SSH tools (i.e. Putty).

Comment: Alright, well thanks for trying to help me understand it. I don't have any idea what VIM is and it seems that somehow I successfully saved my edits to my rc.local file without an editor, but only using the SSH tool called Putty.

Comment: VIM is the editor

Comment: So where did the editor come from if I only used Putty? Is the editor built in to Raspberry Pi and I called it up with the terminal app? Is ".wq" the command to save in VIM as well as Putty?

Comment: Yes, when you are using Putty all the commands (ls, cd, mv etc) and tools (including vim) are those available on the PI. You are simply using putty to access them remotely. There is no save command in Putty. The esc :wq command is not a putty command it is a VIM command.

Comment: Alright, thanks for enlightening me. I was let astray by an informative website about Putty specifically, and it said to save in Putty using .wq. Too bad the person(s) who put together that helpful site didn't realize they were just confusing people like myself.